# Rounding to eliminate decimal

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query below as:

```
SELECT ds, 
       round(count(CASE WHEN action = 'accepted' THEN 1 
             ELSE NULL END) * 1.0 / count(action),2) * 100 as perc
FROM friend_requests
group by 1
```

Output:

```
perc
50.00
100.00
50.00
```

desired output:

```
perc
50
100
50
```

If I want to remove decimals and just have 50 or 100 how can I edit this? I try changing the ,2 parameter in round to ,0 and it just rounds all values to 100

Thanks

Comment: cast as an integer

Comment: Rounding is when you replace some decimal places with other decimal places reducing precision (e.g. `1,234` -> `1,2` or `123` -> `120`). But you need to cast your expression to `int`, so it would be `expression::int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast your `perc` field as an `int` type and remove the `round` function:

```
SELECT
    ds,
    cast(count(CASE WHEN action = 'accepted' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) * 1.0 / count(action) * 100 as int) as perc
FROM friend_requests
group by 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest phrasing the logic as:

```
SELECT ds, 
       round(avg( (action = 'accepted')::int) * 100), 0) as perc
FROM friend_requests
GROUP BY 1
```

Comment: But division and aggregation was lost